Level probabilites from emmeans don't seem to match predicted means from emmeans
When I ask emmeans for model level probabilities I get the highest probabilities near levels 6 and 7 of my ordinal DV:enter image description here
> emmeans(clm_gid_no,
+         ~ value | Response_Condition, mode = "prob")
Response_Condition = null:
 value   prob      SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1     0.0485 0.00778 Inf    0.0333    0.0637
 2     0.0395 0.00697 Inf    0.0258    0.0531
 3     0.0512 0.00786 Inf    0.0358    0.0665
 4     0.0789 0.00945 Inf    0.0604    0.0974
 5     0.1242 0.01087 Inf    0.1029    0.1455
 6     0.1579 0.01139 Inf    0.1356    0.1802
 7     0.4998 0.01779 Inf    0.4650    0.5347

Response_Condition = overt:
 value   prob      SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1     0.0220 0.00390 Inf    0.0143    0.0296
 2     0.0193 0.00364 Inf    0.0121    0.0264
 3     0.0270 0.00444 Inf    0.0183    0.0357
 4     0.0469 0.00609 Inf    0.0350    0.0589
 5     0.0899 0.00867 Inf    0.0729    0.1069
 6     0.1510 0.01122 Inf    0.1290    0.1730
 7     0.6440 0.01897 Inf    0.6068    0.6812

Results are averaged over the levels of: Prompt_Condition 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

When I ask emmeans for predicted means from this same model to make an interaction plot it returns means between levels 1 and 3.5 of the DV for different combos of the two IVs:enter image description here
> emmeans(clm_gid_no, ~ Prompt_Condition*Response_Condition, type = "response")
 Prompt_Condition Response_Condition emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 generic          null                3.347 0.205 Inf     2.946      3.75
 indefinite       null                1.070 0.139 Inf     0.798      1.34
 definite         null                0.991 0.141 Inf     0.714      1.27
 generic          overt               1.708 0.144 Inf     1.426      1.99
 indefinite       overt               3.066 0.189 Inf     2.696      3.44
 definite         overt               2.324 0.161 Inf     2.008      2.64

Confidence level used: 0.95 

Here is the boxplotted data (one IV level has been ignored above):enter image description here
I must not be understanding how emmeans computes model values from its model level probabilities because I would expect model means of between 6 and 7 based on the model level probabilities.
